# how to save attribute value using jQuery and use in the php form?

Tags: jquery, magento

I have created the custom search and get only two values like name and price.

And two buttons "**Add Medicine**" and "**Add More Medicine**".

**for example:**

```
<li>
    <span id="pharmacy-name-1" class="pharmacy-name" data-phone="12154">DIAGNOSTIC PH TEST STRIPS</span> 
    <span id="phamacy-price">$14.99</span>
    <span id="phamacy-btn" class="phamacy-btn" data-phone="12154" data-mname="DIAGNOSTIC PH TEST STRIPS">Add Medicne</span>
    <span id="phamacy-more-btn" data-phone="12154" data-mname="DIAGNOSTIC PH TEST STRIPS">Add More Medicine</span>
</li>
```

When I clicked on **"Add Medicine"** it is showing the popup to submit customer detail with clicked information like name & price. finally, it is submitting perfect.

Now, If I clicked "Add More Medicine":
Customer must be the focus on search input box and the value of the clicked element must be saved for when the customer goes to the popup. and this clicked information should be displayed in the form.

**Popup form jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// open popup when click on Add Medicine button
        $(".pharmacy-list li span#phamacy-btn").click(function(){
            var textvalue = $(this).attr('data-mname');
            var textclass = $(this).attr('data-phone');
            $('#c77').val(textclass);
            $('#c82').val(textvalue);
            $("#transferdetailform").fadeIn();
        });
        $("#cancelpopup").click(function(){
            $("#transferdetailform").fadeOut();
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good so far but you should switch your attribute names. 
The names you are using are not valid. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Change: 
phone to data-phone
mname to data-mname

```
<span id="phamacy-btn" class="phamacy-btn" data-phone="12154" data-mname="DIAGNOSTIC PH TEST STRIPS">Add Medicne</span>
<span id="phamacy-more-btn" data-phone="12154" data-mname="DIAGNOSTIC PH TEST STRIPS">Add More Medicine</span>
```

and switch this part in your jquery script:

```
var textvalue = $(this).attr('data-mname');
var textclass = $(this).attr('data-phone');
```